# Nondecreasing function satisfies $f(a+x)-f(a-x) \geq cx$ for some $a,c$ and for all $x\in[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

The following problem is from "Berkeley Problems in Mathematics" by Souza, Silva.

> *Let  $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be nonconstant and assume $x \leq y$ implies $f(x) \leq f(y)$. Prove that there exist $a \in
>  \mathbb{R}$ and $c > 0$ such that for all $x \in [0,1]$,
> $f(a+x)-f(a-x) \geq cx$.*

The book had the following solution.

> Since $f$ is increasing and nonconstant, there exist $r_0 < s_0$ such
> that $f(r_0) < f(s_0)$. Increasing $s_0$ if necessary, we may assume
> $\delta =s_0-r_0>1$. Let $\Delta =f(s_0)-f(r_0)$. Choose $[r_1,s_1]$
> to be either $[r_0,(r_0+s_0)/2]$ or $[(r_0+s_0)/2, s_0]$, whichever
> makes $f(s_1)-f(r_1)$ larger. (Choose either if they are equal.) Then
> $f(s_1)-f(r_1)\geq \Delta/2$. Similarly choose $[r_2,s_2]$ as the left
> or right half of $[r_1,s_1]$, to maximize $f(s_2)-f(r_2)$, and so on,
> so that $s_i-r_i=2^{-i}\delta$ and $f(s_i)-f(r_i)\geq 2^{-i}\Delta$.
> Let $a=\lim{r_i}$, and set $c=\Delta/(2\delta)$. Given $x\in (0,1]$,
> choose the first integer $i\geq 0$ such that $2^{-i}\delta \leq x$.
> Then $2^{-i}\delta \geq x/2$. Also $[r_i,s_i]$ contains $a$ and is of
> length $\leq x$, so $[r_i,s_i]\subset [a-x,a+x]$. Since $f$ is
> increasing,
>
> $\displaystyle f(a+x)-f(a-x)\geq f(s_i)-f(r_i)\geq 2^{-i}\Delta
> > 2c2^{-i}\delta \geq cx\tag*{}$
>
> Finally, the inequality $f(a+x)-f(a-x)\geq cx$ is immediate for $x=0$.

I think I understand the details of the proof, but I don't understand the big picture of it.

How do we know that I should take half of the intervals and repeat them?  **How do we create the sketch of the proof?**

I think if I could understand the intuitive interpretation of the inequality $f(a+x)-f(a-x) \geq cx$, then it might be clearer, but I don't understand it either. If we write it as $\frac{f(a+x)-f(a-x)}{2x} \geq c/2$, then it looks like a slope of the curve, but I don't know what to do with this idea.